# Install Scipy 1.0.0: AssertionError

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to install scipy 1.0.0 in a conda env for another software called GATK.

I installed python 3.6.10 and numpy 1.17.5, which are said to be compatible with scipy 1.0.0 (both in the yml file provided by GATK)

However, when I tried installing via `python setup.py build`, it returns error message as below. I searched by seems like others are mostly struggling with scipy 1.1.0 or some other errors.

Really appreciate any help!

Thanks!

````
f2py: build/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/scipy/linalg/flapack.pyf
Reading fortran codes...
    Reading file 'build/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/scipy/linalg/flapack.pyf' (format:free)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 418, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "setup.py", line 414, in setup_package
    setup(**metadata)
  File "/home/joyzheng/.conda/envs/gatk4.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 171, in setup
    return old_setup(**new_attr)
  File "/home/joyzheng/.conda/envs/gatk4.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/home/joyzheng/.conda/envs/gatk4.3/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/home/joyzheng/.conda/envs/gatk4.3/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/home/joyzheng/.conda/envs/gatk4.3/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/joyzheng/.conda/envs/gatk4.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/distutils/command/build.py", line 47, in run
    old_build.run(self)
  File "/home/joyzheng/.conda/envs/gatk4.3/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/home/joyzheng/.conda/envs/gatk4.3/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/home/joyzheng/.conda/envs/gatk4.3/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/joyzheng/.conda/envs/gatk4.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 142, in run
    self.build_sources()
  File "/home/joyzheng/.conda/envs/gatk4.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 159, in build_sources
    self.build_extension_sources(ext)
  File "/home/joyzheng/.conda/envs/gatk4.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 319, in build_extension_sources
    sources = self.f2py_sources(sources, ext)
  File "/home/joyzheng/.conda/envs/gatk4.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 535, in f2py_sources
    + ['--build-dir', target_dir, source])
  File "/home/joyzheng/.conda/envs/gatk4.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/f2py/f2py2e.py", line 425, in run_main
    postlist = callcrackfortran(files, options)
  File "/home/joyzheng/.conda/envs/gatk4.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/f2py/f2py2e.py", line 330, in callcrackfortran
    postlist = crackfortran.crackfortran(files)
  File "/home/joyzheng/.conda/envs/gatk4.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/f2py/crackfortran.py", line 3251, in crackfortran
    readfortrancode(files, crackline)
  File "/home/joyzheng/.conda/envs/gatk4.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/f2py/crackfortran.py", line 501, in readfortrancode
    dowithline(finalline)
  File "/home/joyzheng/.conda/envs/gatk4.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/f2py/crackfortran.py", line 796, in crackline
    analyzeline(m, pat[1], line)
  File "/home/joyzheng/.conda/envs/gatk4.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/f2py/crackfortran.py", line 1098, in analyzeline
    last_name = updatevars(typespec, selector, attr, edecl)
  File "/home/joyzheng/.conda/envs/gatk4.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/f2py/crackfortran.py", line 1542, in updatevars
    attrspec = [x.strip() for x in markoutercomma(attrspec).split('@,@')]
  File "/home/joyzheng/.conda/envs/gatk4.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/f2py/crackfortran.py", line 833, in markoutercomma
    assert not f, repr((f, line, l))
AssertionError: (-1, 'intent(in))', 'intent(in))')```

 - List item
````